# How to switch context in appium using javaclient version 9

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

interface ContextAware is depreciated in selenium version 4.17.0 which was providing methods to set context using appium driver.

Now unable to get or get contexts .

Comment: I am using hybrid apps that have NATIVE as well as WEBVIEW context . I just need to switch context from native to webview or vice versa using Java-client 9 or selenium 4.17